# Как я могу обратиться к автоматически созданному CheckBox C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, checkbox, tag

Столкнулся с такой проблемой...

Я автоматически создаю чекбоксы (до этого в начале программы я объявляю **CheckBox box;** для того, чтобы мог их использовать во всей программе):

```
int startLocation = 142;
for (i = 0; i < ingridients.Length; i++)
{ 
    box = new CheckBox(); //Create new checkBox
    box.Tag = i;//CheckBox (Tag 0-..)
    box.TabIndex = 8 + i;//Последовательность "выбора" через TAB
    box.Text = ingridients[i];
    box.AutoSize = true;
    box.Location = new Point(2, startLocation);
        startLocation += 25;
    this.Controls.Add(box);
}
```

и при закрытии окна мне надо пробежаться по выделенным из CheckBox'ов.

Но тут я сталкиваюсь с проблемой: я не могу обратиться ни к одному из чекбоксов, так как имена у них всех одинаковые.

Я пытался сделать так, но **box.Tag[i]** подчеркивается красным и не работает(что, в принципе, логично).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения])

```
for (int n = 0; n<i; n++)
{
    if (box.Tag[n].Checked = true )
    {

    }
}
```

Может быть можно использовать что-то кроме **tag**'a...

Прошу мне помочь!

Буду очень признателен!

P.S. Я только недавно начал пользоваться StackOverflow, так что прошу не быть слишком критичными по отношению ко мнe.

Comment: `я объявляю CheckBox box;` | `создаю чекбоксы`  - подумайте логически, чему будет равен `box`, если он один, а объектов много? Далее `this.Controls.Add(box);` - куда вы их помещаете все и от куда следует брать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ссылки на все контролы хранятся в коллекции `Controls`, у которой есть метод `OfType` (расширение из `System.Linq`), позволяющий отфильтровать их по заданному типу:

```
foreach (CheckBox chbox in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
    if (chbox.Checked) { /*...*/ }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Пути 2:

1.Создать List и добавлять туда инициализированные чекбоксы

```
List<Checkbox> _chBoxLst = new List<Checkbox>();
int startLocation = 142;
for (i = 0; i < ingridients.Length; i++)
{ 
    _chBoxLst (new CheckBox()); //Create new checkBox
    //дальше идентично твоему коду
}
```

2.Пройтись по всем контролам на форме и выделить из них чекбоксы а потом уже делать с этим списком что нужно. (описан в ответе t3f )

*Лично я пошел бы по первому пути. Чисто потому, что если в будущем появятся на форме новые чекбоксы которые логически отвечают за другие вещи, это может создать проблемы.*

Comment: Мне кажется, что этот случай, когда ответ верный, но лучше расписать подробнее (и с примером кода) потому что автор новичок в шарпе.